# how can I click on the polyline to show infowindow that i drawn using drawing manager of google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to click on the polyline after i drawn by using drawing manager of google maps api v3 and I try to use this codes, but it's not work! how?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) { 
if(event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE){ 
    var newPolyline = event.overlay;                        
    var info = "Testing";
google.maps.event.addListener(newPolyline, 'click', function(){
    infowindow.setContent(info);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
polylines.push(newPolyline);
}
});
```